# Iterate Matrix into a cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

Is there a way I can write a for loop that will add a given number of matrix into a cell array.

```
`C1 = [];`
```

So instead of having to write everyone out like:

```
`cell = {}
cell = [cell C1];
cell = [cell C2];
cell = [cell C3];
cell = [cell C4];`
```

Where the number of C is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of `C` matrices is known, then yes you can write a for loop to do this.  At each iteration of the loop, a command string can be built and then evaluated:

```
N = 4;
cellArray = cell(N,1);  % pre-allocate memory for the array
for i=1:N

    % build the command string
    cmd = ['cellArray{i} = C' num2str(i) ';'];

    % evaluate the string
    eval(cmd);

end
```

You could step through the code and see what `cmd` looks like at each iteration.  Note that some developers have some concerns about using the `eval` command.  Since you are building the command to be run at each iteration, it can make debugging (if an error should arise) somewhat more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to do what I wanted it to.